# Laravel 5.1 random 404 errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel 5.1 framework, I have set up my site using WAMP.
I have handled the errors *whoops* as it is giving response header except 200 OK.

Now the problem here is,
sometimes existing routes [i.e. working the very next moment if I try] return 404 page with response header 200 OK.
I am unable to figure it out that in which case it is returning 404 page.
Note that I have my own 404 page designed which I found in the response.

My controller code is as below:

```
public function create($program_id)
{
    $projects = $this->mock->mockprojectlist($program_id);
    return view('mocks.create', compact('program_id', 'projects'));
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you check your web server error log?

Comment: Can you show your controllers? Specifically the pieces that return the views.

Comment: @MinaAbadir , I just checked the error logs it shows [local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.'] M not sure what is happening here

Comment: Seems you have a connection problem with your MySQL, are you connecting to localhost.

Comment: @ba1ar add the code and errors to your question body, so it's correctly formatted.

Comment: @MinaAbadir updated/

Comment: Are you sure that the code is thrown while running this part of code?

Comment: @MinaAbadir Yes, the same. It works sometimes & sometimes it doesn't. & In logs I found the exception for connection refused. I am not sure why it is so